# How to call super method in interface instance?

Tags: java, android, methods, interface, super

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // ...
    dialog.setPositiveButton(getText(R.string.yes), new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

Gives me error on `super` line and I completely understand why. But how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you understand why?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I can totally understand that Gintas_ knows that the `super.onBackPressed` method doesn't exist, but doesn't know how to refer to the `super.onBackPressed` of the enclosing `Activity`. Why not?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super.onBackPressed` in your example refers to `OnClickListener#onBackPressed`, which just doesn't exist, hence your error.

You actually want to reference the `onBackPressed` of your super `Activity` class. To do that, use:

```
MyActivity.super.onBackPressed();
```

Just like `MyActivity.this` refers to the enclosing instance, `MyActivity.super` refers to the  super class of the enclosing instance.

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot that.